# How to save TextVectorization to disk in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, pickle

I have trained a TextVectorization layer (see below), and I want to save it to disk, so that I can reload it next time? I have tried `pickle` and `joblib.dump()`. It does not work.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization 

text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(text_clean) 
    
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=100000, output_mode='tf-idf',ngrams=None)
    
vectorizer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(1024))
```

The generated error is the following:

```py
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array
```

How can I save it?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers

Comment: Can you share the error log when you are trying to save using pickle.

Comment: You can try using following code snippet to save vectorized data into pickle format `pickle.dump(vectorized_text, open("vector.pickel", "wb"))` and load using `vectorizer = pickle.load(open("vector.pickel", "rb"))` function.

Comment: well , it cannot be dumped using the pickle.

Comment: InvalidArgumentError: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array @TFer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of pickling the object, pickle the configuration and weights. Later unpickle it and use configuration to create the object and load the saved weights. Official docs [here](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/).

#### Code

```py
text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
                                                   "this is some clean text", 
                                                   "some more text", 
                                                   "even some more text"]) 
# Fit a TextVectorization layer
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10, output_mode='tf-idf',ngrams=None)    
vectorizer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(1024))

# Vector for word "this"
print (vectorizer("this"))

# Pickle the config and weights
pickle.dump({'config': vectorizer.get_config(),
             'weights': vectorizer.get_weights()}
            , open("tv_layer.pkl", "wb"))

print ("*"*10)
# Later you can unpickle and use 
# `config` to create object and 
# `weights` to load the trained weights. 

from_disk = pickle.load(open("tv_layer.pkl", "rb"))
new_v = TextVectorization.from_config(from_disk['config'])
# You have to call `adapt` with some dummy data (BUG in Keras)
new_v.adapt(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["xyz"]))
new_v.set_weights(from_disk['weights'])

# Lets see the Vector for word "this"
print (new_v("this"))
```

Output:

```py
tf.Tensor(
[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.91629076 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.        ]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)
**********
tf.Tensor(
[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.91629076 0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.        ]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. It works. "new_v.adapt(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["xyz"]))" this command is not necessary, because if I remove this adapt command, it still recover from the dumped vec.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instruction. I am using `tf2.6` and have noticed that in this way, the loaded text vectorization layer produces ragged tensors with no padding. I this this behaviour is due to the `from_config` method.

Comment: @AritraRoyGosthipaty, is there a way to get padded sequences instead of ragged tensors in TF2.6?

Comment: @Nacho I built the tokenizer not from config but the way I did it in the first time. Then just used the `set_weights` to set the weights of the tokenizer. That way I was able to retain the pads.

Comment: Hey, I saved the `TextVectorizer` using this method but my vectorizer uses a custom `standardize` function so when I am trying `from_disk = pickle.load(open("tv_layer.pkl", "rb"))
new_v = TextVectorization.from_config(from_disk['config'])` it is throwing **TypeError: Could not parse config: <function tf_lower_and_split_punct at 0x7fb7959ba160>** error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

One can use a bit of a hack to do this. Construct your `TextVectorization` object, then put it in a model. Save the model to save the vectorizer. Loading the model will reproduce the vectorizer. See the example below.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization

data = [
    "The sky is blue.",
    "Grass is green.",
    "Hunter2 is my password.",
]

# Create vectorizer.
text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
vectorizer = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=100000, output_mode='tf-idf', ngrams=None,
)
vectorizer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(1024))

# Create model.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(vectorizer)

# Save.
filepath = "tmp-model"
model.save(filepath, save_format="tf")

# Load.
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath)
loaded_vectorizer = loaded_model.layers[0]
```

Here is a test that both vectorizers (original and loaded) produce the same output.

```py
import numpy as np

np.testing.assert_allclose(loaded_vectorizer("blue"), vectorizer("blue"))
```

Comment: How is that a hack!? :)

Comment: You could also serialize the layer to JSON, dump, load and deserialize. Surely a matter of taste though?

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: @jtlz2 - you're right, it's not a hack :) i don't know if serializing to json will maintain the parameters from `vectorizer.adapt`. can you test if the vectorizer loaded from json gives the same output as the original vectorizer?

Comment: you are right, it does not save the vocabulary! :(

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing @jakub's model-vehicle trick - with which I couldn't get the model to load - I did in the end go via the JSON serialization route, as follows.

Note that you need to have tensorflow>=2.7 for the `TextVectorization` layer, and you need to use the same version to save and load the layer/model.

So, following on from the middle of @jakub's brilliant sample,

```py
# Save.
model_json = model.to_json()
with open(filepath, "w") as model_json_fh:
    model_json_fh.write(model_json)

# Load.
with open(filepath, 'r') as model_json_fh:
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(model_json_fh.read())
    vectorization_layer = loaded_model.layers[0]

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath)
loaded_vectorizer = loaded_model.layers[0]
```

That's it.

I am not sure of the advantages of the one route over the other.

This also shows how it goes:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models

And this helps with a JSON error you may encounter on your travels in these parts:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6971

Answer (score 0):

For one anyone asking themselves how to get a `dense` tensor instead of `ragged` tensor when loading the config of a `TextVectorization` layer, try explicitly setting the `output_mode`. The problem is related to a very recent bug, where the `output_mode` is not set correctly when it comes from a saved configuration.

This results in a `dense` Tensor:

```py
text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
                                                   "this is some clean text", 
                                                   "some more text", 
                                                   "even some more text"]) 
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10, output_mode='int', output_sequence_length = 10)   
vectorizer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(1024))

print(vectorizer("this"))
pickle.dump({'config': vectorizer.get_config(),
             'weights': vectorizer.get_weights()}
            , open("tv_layer.pkl", "wb"))

from_disk = pickle.load(open("tv_layer.pkl", "rb"))
new_vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=from_disk['config']['max_tokens'],
                                          output_mode='int',
                                          output_sequence_length=from_disk['config']['output_sequence_length'])
new_vectorizer.adapt(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["xyz"]))
new_vectorizer.set_weights(from_disk['weights'])

print(new_vectorizer("this"))
```

```
tf.Tensor([5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
```

This results in a `ragged` Tensor when loading:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
                                                   "this is some clean text", 
                                                   "some more text", 
                                                   "even some more text"]) 
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10, output_mode='int', output_sequence_length = 10)   
vectorizer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(1024))

print(vectorizer("this"))
pickle.dump({'config': vectorizer.get_config(),
             'weights': vectorizer.get_weights()}
            , open("tv_layer.pkl", "wb"))

from_disk = pickle.load(open("tv_layer.pkl", "rb"))
new_vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=from_disk['config']['max_tokens'],
                                          output_mode=from_disk['config']['output_mode'],
                                          output_sequence_length=from_disk['config']['output_sequence_length'])
new_vectorizer.adapt(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["xyz"]))
new_vectorizer.set_weights(from_disk['weights'])

print(new_vectorizer("this"))
```

```
tf.Tensor([5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)
```