# a bug for tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization when built from saved configs and weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have tried writing a python program to save tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization to disk and load it with the answer of [How to save TextVectorization to disk in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103526/how-to-save-textvectorization-to-disk-in-tensorflow).
The TextVectorization layer built from saved configs outputs a vector with wrong length when the arg `output_sequence_length` is not `None` and `output_mode='int'`.
For example, if I set `output_sequence_length= 10`, and `output_mode='int'`, it is expected that given a text, TextVectorization should output a vector with length of 10, see `vectorizer` and `new_v2` in the code below.
However, if TextVectorization's arg `output_mode='int'` is set from saved configs, it doesn't output a vector with length of 10(actually it is 9, the real length of the sentence. It seems like `output_sequence_length` is not set successfully). See the object `new_v1` in the code below.
The interesting thing is, I have compared `from_disk['config']['output_mode']` and `'int'`, they equal to each other.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import pickle
# In[]
max_len = 10  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
                                                   "I like natural language processing",
                                                   "You like computer vision",
                                                   "I like computer games and computer science"])
# Fit a TextVectorization layer
VOCAB_SIZE = 10  # Maximum vocab size.
vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=None,
        standardize="lower_and_strip_punctuation",
        split="whitespace",
        output_mode='int',
        output_sequence_length=max_len
        )
vectorizer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(64))
# In[]
#print(vectorizer.get_vocabulary())
#print(vectorizer.get_config())
#print(vectorizer.get_weights())
# In[]


# Pickle the config and weights
pickle.dump({'config': vectorizer.get_config(),
             'weights': vectorizer.get_weights()}
            , open("./models/tv_layer.pkl", "wb"))


# Later you can unpickle and use
# `config` to create object and
# `weights` to load the trained weights.

from_disk = pickle.load(open("./models/tv_layer.pkl", "rb"))

new_v1 = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=None,
        standardize="lower_and_strip_punctuation",
        split="whitespace",
        output_mode=from_disk['config']['output_mode'],
        output_sequence_length=from_disk['config']['output_sequence_length'],
        )
# You have to call `adapt` with some dummy data (BUG in Keras)
new_v1.adapt(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["xyz"]))
new_v1.set_weights(from_disk['weights'])
new_v2 = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=None,
        standardize="lower_and_strip_punctuation",
        split="whitespace",
        output_mode='int',
        output_sequence_length=from_disk['config']['output_sequence_length'],
        )

# You have to call `adapt` with some dummy data (BUG in Keras)
new_v2.adapt(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["xyz"]))
new_v2.set_weights(from_disk['weights'])
print ("*"*10)
# In[]
test_sentence="Jack likes computer scinece, computer games, and foreign language"

print(vectorizer(test_sentence))
print (new_v1(test_sentence))
print (new_v2(test_sentence))
print(from_disk['config']['output_mode']=='int')
```

Here are the print() outputs:

```
**********
tf.Tensor([ 1  1  3  1  3 11 12  1 10  0], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([ 1  1  3  1  3 11 12  1 10], shape=(9,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([ 1  1  3  1  3 11 12  1 10  0], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
True
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I am afraid it is quite unclear what *exactly* your issue is.

Comment: @desertnaut I have edited my question. is it clear now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the bug is fixed by the PR in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/15422

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And what's the workaround in the meantime?