# How to save Keras TextVectorization layer configuration with custom standardization function into a pickle file and reload it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have a `Keras TextVectorization` layer which uses a custom standardization function.

```
def custom_standardization(input_string, preserve=['[', ']'], add=['¿']):

    strip_chars = string.punctuation
    for item in add:
        strip_chars += item
    
    for item in preserve:
        strip_chars = strip_chars.replace(item, '')

    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_string)
    output = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, f'[{re.escape(strip_chars)}]', '')

    return output
```

```
target_vectorization = keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=vocab_size,
                                                output_mode='int',
                                                output_sequence_length=sequence_length + 1,
                                                standardize=custom_standardization)
```

```
target_vectorization.adapt(train_spanish_texts)
```

I want to save the adapted configuration for an inference model to make use of.

One way, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225240/15281128), is to save the `weights` and `config` separately as a pickle file and reload them.

However, `target_vectorization.get_config()`  returns

```
{'name': 'text_vectorization_5',
 'trainable': True,
 ...
 'standardize': <function __main__.custom_standardization(input_string, preserve=['[', ']'], add=['¿'])>,
 ...
 'vocabulary_size': 15000}
```

which is being saved into the pickle file.

Trying to load this config using `keras.layers.TextVectorization.from_config(pickle.load(open('ckpts/spanish_vectorization.pkl', 'rb'))['config'])` results in `TypeError: Could not parse config: <function custom_standardization at 0x2a1973a60>`, because the file does not have any information about this custom standardization function.

What is a good way to save the TextVectorization weights and configuration for an inference model to make use of, in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to define a wrapper around the TextVectorization object and use the custom standardizer as a method. Moreover, we needed to exclude callable objects while saving configuration to the pickle file. Here's the fixed code:

```
@keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='custom_layers', name='TextVectorizer')
class TextVectorizer(layers.Layer):
    '''English - Spanish Text Vectorizer'''

    def __init__(self, max_tokens=None, output_mode='int', output_sequence_length=None, standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation', vocabulary=None, config=None):
        super().__init__()
        if config:
            self.vectorization = layers.TextVectorization.from_config(config)

        else:
            self.max_tokens = max_tokens
            self.output_mode = output_mode
            self.output_sequence_length = output_sequence_length
            self.vocabulary = vocabulary
            if standardize != 'lower_and_strip_punctuation':
                self.vectorization = layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=self.max_tokens,
                                                              output_mode=self.output_mode,
                                                              output_sequence_length=self.output_sequence_length,
                                                              vocabulary=self.vocabulary,
                                                              standardize=self.standardize)
            else:
                self.vectorization = layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=self.max_tokens,
                                                              output_mode=self.output_mode,
                                                              output_sequence_length=self.output_sequence_length,
                                                              vocabulary=self.vocabulary)


    def standardize(self, input_string, preserve=['[', ']'], add=['¿']) -> str:
        strip_chars = string.punctuation
        for item in add:
            strip_chars += item
    
        for item in preserve:
            strip_chars = strip_chars.replace(item, '')

        lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_string)
        output = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, f'[{re.escape(strip_chars)}]', '')

        return output

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.vectorization.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        return {key: value if not callable(value) else None for key, value in self.vectorization.get_config().items()}

    def from_config(config):
        return TextVectorizer(config=config)

    def set_weights(self, weights):
        self.vectorization.set_weights(weights)

    def adapt(self, dataset):
        self.vectorization.adapt(dataset)

    def get_vocabulary(self):
        return self.vectorization.get_vocabulary()
```

To adapt and save weights [Training Phase]:

```
vocab_size = 15000
sequence_length = 20

source_vectorization = TextVectorizer(max_tokens=vocab_size,
                                      output_mode='int',
                                      output_sequence_length=sequence_length)

target_vectorization = TextVectorizer(max_tokens=vocab_size,
                                      output_mode='int',
                                      output_sequence_length=sequence_length + 1,
                                      standardize='spanish')

train_english_texts = [pair[0] for pair in train_pairs]
train_spanish_texts = [pair[1] for pair in train_pairs]
source_vectorization.adapt(train_english_texts)
target_vectorization.adapt(train_spanish_texts)

pickle.dump({'config': source_vectorization.get_config(),
             'weights': source_vectorization.get_weights()}, open('ckpts/english_vectorization.pkl', 'wb'))

pickle.dump({'config': target_vectorization.get_config(),
             'weights': target_vectorization.get_weights()}, open('ckpts/spanish_vectorization.pkl', 'wb'))
```

To load and use them [Inference Phase]:

```
vectorization_data = pickle.load(open('ckpts/english_vectorization.pkl', 'rb'))
source_vectorization = TextVectorizer.from_config(vectorization_data['config'])
source_vectorization.set_weights(vectorization_data['weights'])

vectorization_data = pickle.load(open('ckpts/spanish_vectorization.pkl', 'rb'))
target_vectorization = TextVectorizer.from_config(vectorization_data['config'])
target_vectorization.set_weights(vectorization_data['weights'])
```

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM

It seems a problem related to serialize a custom standardize callable. See the docs here: ([tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization)).

SOLUTION

The doc states that you should register the layer as a keras serializable object with a wrapper class with the following decorator ([tf.keras.saving.register_keras_serializable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization)).

I have tested a minimal working example with your custom function, and this example works in python 3.9.12 and keras/tensorflow 2.15:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import string
import re
import pickle

def custom_standardization(input_string, preserve=['[', ']'], add=['¿']):
    strip_chars = string.punctuation
    for item in add:
        strip_chars += item

    for item in preserve:
        strip_chars = strip_chars.replace(item, '')

    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_string)
    output = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, f'[{re.escape(strip_chars)}]', '')

    return output

@keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='custom_layers', name='TextVectorizer')
class TextVectorizer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, custom_standardization, **kwargs):
        super(TextVectorizer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.custom_standardization = custom_standardization
        self.vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
            standardize=self.custom_standardization,
            max_tokens=1000,  # You can adjust this parameter based on your dataset
            output_mode='int'
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.vectorizer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(TextVectorizer, self).get_config()
        return config

# Example usage
text_vectorizer = TextVectorizer(custom_standardization)

# Adapt the TextVectorization layer to your training data
train_data = tf.constant(['Hello [World]!', 'Another [example].'])
text_vectorizer.vectorizer.adapt(train_data)

# Build the layer to initialize the TextVectorization layer
text_vectorizer.build(input_shape=(None,))

# Create a model to include the TextVectorization layer
model = tf.keras.Sequential([text_vectorizer])
model.build(input_shape=())
# Save the weights of the model
model.save_weights('text_vectorizer_weights.tf')

# Load the weights into a new instance of TextVectorization
loaded_text_vectorizer = TextVectorizer(custom_standardization)
loaded_text_vectorizer.build(input_shape=(None,))

# Create a model to include the loaded TextVectorization layer
loaded_model = tf.keras.Sequential([loaded_text_vectorizer])

# Adapt the TextVectorization layer to the same training data
loaded_text_vectorizer.vectorizer.adapt(train_data)

# Load the weights into the new model
loaded_model.load_weights('text_vectorizer_weights.tf')

# Compile the model after loading the weights
loaded_model.compile()

# Test the loaded layer
text_input = tf.constant(['Hello [World]!'])
output = loaded_model(text_input)
print(output)
```

Comment: A few things:
1. You are adapting to the same training data after loading the model. This defeats the entire purpose of encapsulating the inference model in the absence of training data.
2. The pipeline 'Add layer to keras Sequential' - 'save model' - 'load model' - 'extract layer' does not seem to work, and is resulting in gibberish translations.

Comment: Can you send the log of the error so I can debug and provide a better answer? Did you tested it with the versions I provided at the beginning?